# Need help on checking Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: boot, 14.04, live-cd

I have created an Ubuntu Live CD. I succesfully verified the sha256 sum of the .iso file using the intructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToSHA256SUM

The problem is the next part on the page above which is to "Check the CD". After I burn the .iso I follow the instructions and enter sha256sum /dev/cdrom in terminal

Then I check the output against the [Ubuntu Hashes page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) except the output doesn't match. It is quite a bit longer than the ones listed on the page. Am I checking in the write place? Need some help with this.

They also mention a way of checking the integrity of the CD when you boot it: "So far so good, you have downloaded an iso and verified its integrity. When you boot from the CD you will be given the option to test its integrity."

I do not see this option at all.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ubuntu Hashes page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)  doesn't list SHA256 hashes but only MD5 hashes.

See http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/SHA256SUMS for SHA256 hashes of the 14.04 images.

Comment: I did notice that. I was just following instructions so it could be a minor error. Thank you for your help.